# Can't convert a variable to Guid

Tags: c#-4.0, type-conversion, guid

I know my question is really easy but i can't get its solution since last three hours.

I have created a gridview which has three columns PeriodID,PeriodName and Checkbox.

now when i go through for each loop for this grid,i want to get periodid value of each row in this gridview..

for this i have writen code like this.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvdchk.Rows)
        {
            int i = row.RowIndex;
            var cb = (HtmlInputCheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPaid");
            var Periodid = gvdchk.Rows[i].FindControl("PeriodID");
            //string su = Periodid.ToString();
           // Guid PeriodID = Guid.Parse(su);
           // Guid guid = new Guid(Periodid);
            //var PeriodID = row.FindControl("PeriodID");
            //Guid PeriodId = (Guid) PeriodID;
            //Guid PeriodId = (Guid)(gvdchk.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("datemonth2"));

           // int order = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPeriod.GetOrder(PeriodID);
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {

            }
        }
```

When I debug my code,I found that var Periodid gets the correct value of the period id but I want it as Guid.

Can anyone help in this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code that you have in your post 
`Guid guid = new Guid(Periodid);` 
will work fine to convert the string to GUID.

You can also check what is the datatype for the Periodid that you get in the line no. 5 of your code.

Comment: @ saravanan ..Thanks..I have tried all the above thing..But the problem was something else.